# Can an Azure virtual machine scale set have a hidden public IP?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster with 2 nodepools (one was added later). My problem is that only the first nodepool (the one created with the cluster) has a public ip which can be found in azure portal (as a public ip resource). Is it possible to find the IP of the second nodepool somewhere in the portal? I know what the IP is because I pinged one of my servers from a pod running on that nodepool, but I need the resource (or at least it's ID). I also tried searching for it using [azure resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com) but I couldn't find anything related to it. Is it hidden?

Sorry if the question seems dumb. I hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably dealing with an ephemeral external IP, so whenever there is no public ip attached to a vm it gets assigned an ephemeral one for outgoing comms. You can also read this article to get a better idea how to control that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections

Comment: Thanks! I have a basic load balancer so I guess I'm in the 3rd scenario, right? Wich means that since the "public IP address isn't configurable and can't be reserved" I can't see it anywhere in the portal

Comment: if you have a lb attached to the vmss you can take a look at the lb frontend configuration to figure out the IP

Comment: Only the first vmss (the one created with the cluster) has a load balancer attached to it. The second vmss does not have one.

Comment: if it's not attached you are in the scenario I mentioned: ephemeral ip gets assigned, assign a pip or an lb to control that